# Separate server's hostname appearing in this server's cron logs

Tags: cron, hostname, syslog

I get entries like these in /var/log/cron, in a host named `SERV2` (RHEL 6.2):

```
Apr 21 14:50:01 SERV1 CROND[14799]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -S DISK 1 1)
Apr 21 15:20:01 serv2 CROND[24438]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -S DISK 1 1)
Apr 21 15:00:01 SERV1 CROND[14838]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -S DISK 1 1)
```

Entries with `SERV1` seem to be coming from other host, but AFAIK cron doesn't work in a distributed way, just as a local service. How can those entries end up here?

More info:

```
# hostname
SERV2

# cat /etc/hosts
10.22.1.70    serv2
10.22.1.27    serv1
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: interesting that serv2's entry is timestamped earlier than the following SERV1 entry

Comment: actually just noticed that serv2's time is not correct (20 minutes more than the real time). serv1 is correct

Comment: it looks to me like serv1's syslog is configured to send (at least) cron messages to serv2. Do you see any @ symbols if you do `grep cron /etc/rsyslog.conf` on serv1?

Comment: Not with `grep cron` but with just `grep`, I find `*.* @10.22.1.70:514`. I was looking in cron config and not syslog config. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [syslog format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#page-8) typically contains a timestamp, hostname, app name, and process ID along with whatever custom message was sent. All of these values are (substantially) under the control of the process that sends the syslog message. The [cronie](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/cronie.git/tree/src/misc.c#n521) source (if configured to use syslog) uses the [openlog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog) and [syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) functions to write to syslog.

Seeing that the reported messages looked like syslog format, and that the hostnames were different between the messages, and that all of the (mentioned) logs were from the CROND "app name", it seemed plausible that SERV2's syslog was configured to write all "cron" facility logs that it receives to the /var/log/cron file. This would include "remote" logs from other systems that were configured to send their syslogs to SERV2 (and assuming that SERV2 is listening for those remote logs).

This theory was confirmed in the comments when the OP found that serv1 had a wildcard syslog entry that pointed every syslog at (presumably the IP of) SERV2.