# /var/log/messages reports non existent user

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I'm trying to understand what is the third parameter in my `/var/log/messages` file. For example:

```
$ logger test
$ grep test /var/log/messages
```

Output:

```
May 20 15:32:57 hostname **myusername**: test
```

Sometimes **myusername** is a process name, like **httpd**. But
what's driving me crazy is that there are some lines that contain **nonexistent user**/**daemon**

For example:

```
May 20 15:32:57 hostname weirdname: some-http-request-here
```

What is **weirdname**? It's not in my `/etc/passwd`, not in my `/etc/group`, and is not a daemon/program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278244/117549 -

> The syslog format typically contains a timestamp, hostname, app name, and process ID along with whatever custom message was sent.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#page-14:

> The APP-NAME field SHOULD identify the device or application that
> originated the message.  It is a string without further semantics. It is intended for filtering messages on a relay or collector. The NILVALUE MAY be used when the syslog application has no idea of its APP-NAME or cannot provide that information.

Try an example (Linux) for yourself:

```
logger -t weirdername "hello, self"
```

Comment: Thank you! I now understand that most probably Apache is responsible for this "weirdname" being logged. Instead of writing **httpd** to the log, it'd write **weirdname** as that was configured as one of the virtualhosts.